# mysql match against multiple words

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Below is an example sql I am stuck with, it will not return a product named "iphone 4s", It returns 10 other result. Any help would be great thanks

### 1st sql example

```
SELECT * FROM products 
          WHERE match(desc) against('+iphone +4s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10";
```

result: contains the words 'iphone' and '4s'

### 2nd sql example

```
SELECT * FROM products 
           WHERE match(desc) against('+iphone 4s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10";
```

result: contains the words 'iphone', but rank rows higher if they also contain '4s'

### 3rd sql example

```
SELECT * FROM products 
           WHERE match(desc) against('iphone 4s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10";
```

result: contains the words 'iphone' or '4s'

What I want to search is 'iphone 4s', but it comes with other result, like 'iphone is good, but 4s...', 'new iphone 5 has published...',...

Can anyone help me to solve it? thanks.

Comment: you can do it easily with like operator if its not must to use match - against.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To match an exact phrase, just use double quotes to surround the phrase to match;

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE MATCH(desc) 
      AGAINST('"iphone 4s"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
LIMIT 10
```

[More info at the manual pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE desc REGEXP 'iphone[[. .]]*4s'
LIMIT 10;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82dd2/1)